# Five lines of $\mathbb{P}^2$ determine a conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to prove that given $L_1, . . . , L_5$ in the projective plane be five arbitrary lines, there exists a conic C that is tangent to all of those lines.

I have studied that through the Gauss map there is a correspondence between a smooth curve and the lines tangent to one point of the curve. And those lines are points in the dual projective plane. But what happens if the curve is not smooth?

On the other hand those 5 points on the dual will determine a conic in the dual projective plane, but not in the projective plane ??

Comment: If a conic is given by its matrix, the dual is given by the adjugate matrix, or when the determinant is non-zero, the inverse.

Comment: where can i found a proof for that?

Answer (score 2):

See e.g. [Richter-Gebert, J. (2011). Conics and Their Duals. In: Perspectives on Projective Geometry](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-17286-1_9)

or

**Example 2.1. p. 18** in [Gelfand, I.M., Kapranov, M.M., Zelevinsky, A.V. (1994). Projective Dual Varieties and General Discriminants. In: Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional Determinants.](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4771-1_2)

Let $X \subseteq {\Bbb P}^2$ be a smooth conic. In homogeneous coordinates,
which we now prefer to denote by $x_1, x_2, x_3$, the curve $X$ is given by
$$(Ax, x) =\sum_{i,j=1}^{3} a_{ij} x_i x_j=0,$$
where $A = (a_{ij})$ is a non-degenerate symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrix. We claim that
$X^{\vee} \subseteq {\Bbb P}^{2*}$ is also a conic curve defined by the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$. It is clear that the tangent line to $X$ at a point $x^{(0)}\in X$ is given by $(Ax^{(0)}, x) = 0$. Hence the point $\xi\in {\Bbb P}^{2*}$ corresponding to this tangent line has homogeneous coordinates
$Ax^{(0)}$ which implies $(A^{-1} \xi, \xi) = 0$.